# Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 550 HELO using nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

We are gettting error Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 550 HELO can't be [127.0.0.1]. Please contact your ISP.

The below code was working up to last month and now its throwing error.But same mail configuration working while using c#.

```
`const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
port: 587,
host: "smtp.online.net", 
auth: {
    user: 'info@domain.com',
    pass: 'xxxxx',
},
secure: false
```

});

```
const mailData = {
    from: 'info@domain.com',
    to: "test@test.com",
    subject: 'subject',       
    html: 'message'  
};

transporter.sendMail(mailData, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    
    console.log('Sent');
});`
```